# How to get the integer part only from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string as follows '$123,456.12'. i want to get rhe value integer value of the string 123456.

I have tried using this function

```
int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, number))))
```

but it returns 12345612.

Is there any other solution ?

Comment: One option is `int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, number.split('.')[0]))))`/

Comment: s.split('.')[0].replace('$','').replace(',','')

or

    re.sub('\$|,|\.[0-9]+','',s)

also work

Comment: You could also use regex: `re.search(r'([0-9,]+)', '$123,456.12').group(1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
data = '$123,456.12'

print (int(''.join(list(filter(str.isdigit, data.split('.')[0])))))
# or
print (int(''.join(i for i in data.split('.')[0] if i.isdigit())))
```

output:

```
123456
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = '$123,456.12'
end = x.index('.')
int(x[1:end].replace(',', ''))
```